# universal ctags with vim for c++

Tags: vim, ctags, universal-ctags

I have recently started working on a huge c++ codebase and I am unable to use ctags(universal-ctags) properly.
Whenever I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on a method, it jumps to the namespace definition. But I want it to jump to the definition of the method under the cursor.

I generated the tags file using the following:

```
ctags -R --sort=no --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++ .
```

I would really appreciate any help regarding this or is there any better way to navigate c++ code other than ctags.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `ctags --list-kinds=C++` to see what can be tagged and what is enabled by default. Note `n` next to "namespaces". Therefore to disable tagging of namespaces, you should replace `--c++-kinds=+p` with `--c++-kinds=+p-n` in your command used to generate tags:

```
ctags -R --sort=no --c++-kinds=+p-n --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --language-force=C++
```

If you don't want to disable tagging of namespaces, do `g]` on a method instead of `CTRL-]`. You can then enter a number to select the tag you want. Note the "type" column. Select the one with `f` if you want to jump to the function or method.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! The `g]` works but even after running `--c++-kinds=+p-n` the output of `ctags --list-kinds=C++` does not change. The funciton protoypes shows [off]

Comment: Sorry, I think my answer was not clear. I've changed it a bit. I hope this helps.